# Is it possible to build a file in the parent directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, output

I have a folder structure in the project as seen in the picture:

[image]

and I would like to have the `SettingsManagementTest.mvconfig` File to be directly in the Release/Debug folder. But it is always built into a subfolder called SettingsManagement.

Is this even possible or should think of another solution?

Comment: You can drag the file onto the project and it will be in the root of your debug/release folder, just like `packages.config`

Comment: @Phate01 yes, but I would like the file to be in the project folder it is currently in but to be built in the release folder

Answer (score 0):

Call `var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` and you will land in your Debug folder. I recommend printing `currentDir` out once so you have a better understanding of what the method returns.

You can call `var bin = Directory.GetParent(currentDir);` to path into your `bin` folder.

You use `var release = Path.Combine(bin, "Release");` to path into your Release folder.

To create your desired file in the Release folder you can call `File.Create(Path.Combine(release, "SettingsManagementTest.mvconfig"));`

Comment: I know, but I would like to do this without code just with building settings if it's possible

Comment: Then just print out the path to your Release folder, open notepad and save the file as "SettingsManagementTest.mvconfig" (dont forget to swap the file type) and paste the path into the Save-Explorer

Comment: If this doesn't work with the regular Windows Notepad, you should install Notepad++ (in case you didn't install it yet)

Comment: But i dont see this being possible with building settings tbh

Comment: I don't think you get what I am trying to reach. I want the file to be built into this folder just by pressing "Ctrl-Shift-B", like everything else gets built. But I do not want it to be built in the folder it is in the project but in the parent directory. Without having to do anything manually.

Comment: yes, I thought it would not be possible but it's worth a shot

Comment: maybe check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019#directory-and-path-values but i dont think that its gonna solve your problem

Comment: you could maybe write a program that you paste your folder link to which creates the file with given settings for you, but tbh thats pretty much over the top

Comment: yes, I guess I gotta accept that it does not work.

Comment: you can try to develop your own extension that handles your problem, so check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019 . I've never written one by myself but I make much use of Resharper which modifies VS to a very extended amount, so an extension might be your only way to handle your problem